# Load array elements until value is found

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array loading column references from column C.
[image]

The user will enter the current month, e.g. March, then the array should load February column value "U" and January value "L", then the rest of my code will run.

How do I setup the array to stop after the value "L" is found?

```vb
Sub CopyData() 'with array
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wkshtname As String
    Dim colArray(1 To 5) As Variant
    Dim i As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lrow As Long, colcounter As Long, y As Long, retcol As Long, z As Long
    Dim StartHere As String, x As String, col As String
    Dim cell
    Dim sht As Worksheet
        
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    wkshtname = "Retro-" & wb1.Sheets("Instructions").Range("B4").Value
    StartHere = wb1.Sheets("Instructions").Range("B4")
    lrow = wb1.Sheets("Member Prem.Pymts").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If StartHere = "January" Then
        MsgBox "No Retro Commissions to be posted", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    'delete sheet if it exists
    For Each sht In wb1.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = wkshtname Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next sht
    
    With wb1
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = wkshtname
   
        With .Sheets(wkshtname)
            .Cells(1).Resize(1, 8).Value = Array("ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Premium", "Commission Amt", "month for", "agent", "sheet row")
        End With
    
        'returns Paid in Month 30-150 day columns
        col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(StartHere, wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("$A$1:$A$13"), 0)
        
        z = 1
        For retcol = 1 To 5
            colArray(retcol) = wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Cells(col - z, 3)
            z = z + 1
        Next retcol

        With .Sheets("Member Prem.Pymts") 'reference target sheet
            y = 1
            For colcounter = LBound(colArray, 1) To UBound(colArray, 1)
                x = 4 'starting row number data is found on
                For Each i In .Range(colArray(colcounter) & "4:" & colArray(colcounter) & lrow) 'loop through Member Prem.Payments column cells
                    If i.Value = StartHere Then
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("A" & x)
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("B" & x)
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("C" & x)
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("BR" & x)
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wb1.Sheets("Commissions to Pay").Range(wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Cells(col - y, 4) & x)
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range(colArray(colcounter) & "2")
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("DR" & x)
                        wb1.Sheets(wkshtname).Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = x
                    End If
                
                    x = x + 1
                
                Next

                y = y + 1
        
            Next colcounter
        End With


End Sub
```

This is what is stored in the array when I run the code.
I'm trying to load the array and then the array needs to stop loading after the value is "L".

The array will never have more than 5 elements.
[image]

Comment: Your code cannot work declaring `col` variable `As String`. Since it is obtained as a `Match` function return, it cannot be a `String`. It is good to be declared `As Variant` and avoid using `col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(...`, which returns a fatal error in case of no match. You should use `col = Application.Match(...`, which does not return a fatal error, stopping the code. If `Variant`, it can be checked as `If not IsError(col) Then` and do the rest of the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Stripped down to the core problem for testing

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    
    Dim rngMonths As Range, c As Range, wb1
    Dim colArray(), StartHere, col, retcol As Long
   
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rngMonths = wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("A2:A13")   'month lookup range
    StartHere = "March" 'for testing
    
    col = Application.Match(StartHere, rngMonths, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(col) Then
        Set c = rngMonths.Cells(col)
        ReDim colArray(1 To 5)               '<<<<<<<<<<<<
        For retcol = 1 To 5
            colArray(retcol) = c.Offset(0, 2).Value         'col C value
            If colArray(retcol) = "L" Then Exit For         'exit if Col C="L"
            Set c = c.Offset(-1)                            'next cell up
        Next retcol
        ReDim Preserve colArray(1 To retcol) '<<<<<resize array
        Debug.Print Join(colArray, ",")
    Else
        MsgBox "No month match!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. that works perfect. one more question. would i have to redim the array since the code that i'm writing after that should only read the array up until January?

Comment: Is 5 the max number of "lookback" months?  So if starting in November we only go back through Oct to June ?

Comment: yes 5 is the max of lookback months.

Comment: See edit above just after `Next retcol`

Comment: i get a compile error: Array already dimensioned

Comment: My bad - see edit above - tested OK for me.